# Troubles with Trie

Tags: c, trie

So, I was trying to read a Trie, relatively a new data structure for me. And where ever I read, every node in the trie, would consist of an integer variable which would mark the end of an word, and would also consist of 26 pointers, each pointing to nodes in the lower level(assuming the words only contain small letter characters).

Now the problem I am facing is, where ever I see/read the implementation, they mark the node with a character. Like in this case:

http://community.topcoder.com/i/education/alg_tries.png

But the way I am understanding Trie, I believe that every edge should be marked as a character. Although, I know we don't have a data structure for the edges, just for the nodes. But wouldn't marking the edges be more correct?

Also, this is my algorithm for implementing insert. Please tell me if you find something wrong with it.

```
struct trie
{
    int val;
    trie* aplha[26];
}


trie* insert (trie *root, char *inp)
{
    if (*input == '\0')
        return root;

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        root = (trie *) malloc(sizeof(trie));
        int i = 0;
        for (i=0;i<26;i++)
            root->alpha[i] = NULL;
    }

    temp = *input - 'a';
    root->alpha[temp] = insert (root->alpha[temp],input+1);
    if (*(input+1)=='\0')
        root->val = 1;
    return root;
}
```

I am stumped as to how I could implement the delete. If you can, please help me with a delete algorithm.

Comment: Every node has exactly one edge entering it, so you can either draw the letters on the edges or on the nodes they point to; it comes to the same thing.

Comment: Okay, but I am not incorrect when I say that the edges have weights and not the nodes, or am I?

Comment: You can think about it whichever way makes more sense to you.  It doesn't matter.

Comment: @user2560730 Yes, it is much more natural (as far as I can see) to think of the edges as having letters than the nodes having them. This is the way finite state machines are notated, and tries are really just a special case of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small program that shows a way you can do it. There is no serious effort put into error handling though:

http://pastebin.com/84TiPrtL

I've slightly edited your trie_insert function and show a trie_delete function here. The `struct Vec` inside the pastebin code can be changed to a `std::vector` if you are using C++.

```
struct trie *trie_insert(struct trie *root, char *input)
{
    int idx;
    if (!input) {
        return root;
    }
    if (root == NULL) {
        root = (struct trie *)calloc(1, sizeof(struct trie));
    }
    if (*input == '\0') {
        // leaves have root->val set to 1
        root->val = 1;
    } else {
        // carry on insertion
        idx = *input - 'a';
        root->alpha[idx] = trie_insert(root->alpha[idx], input+1);
    }
    return root;
}

struct trie *trie_delete(struct trie *root, char *s)
{
    int i, idx, reap = 0;
    if (!root || !s) {
        return root;
    }
    if (!*s && root->val) {
        // delete this string, and mark node as deletable
        root->val = 0;
        reap = 1;
    } else {
        // more characters to insert, carry on
        idx = *s - 'a';
        if (root->alpha[idx]) {
            root->alpha[idx] = trie_delete(root->alpha[idx], s+1);
            if (!root->alpha[idx]) {
                // child node deleted, set reap = 1
                reap = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // We can delete this if both:
    // 1. reap is set to 1, which is only possible if either:
    //    a. we are now at the end of the string and root->val used
    //       to be 1, but is now set to 0
    //    b. the child node has been deleted
    // 2. The string ending at the current node is not inside the trie,
    //    so root->val = 0
    if (reap && !root->val) {
        for (i = 0; i < NRALPHA; i++) {
            if (root->alpha[i]) {
                reap = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        // no more children, delete this node
        if (reap) {
            trie_free(root);
            root = NULL;
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Comment: What purpose does this condition serve(in the insert function): if (!input)
        return root;

Comment: It checks if the `input` parameter is a NULL pointer. If it is a NULL pointer, there is no string to speak of, so we just return the root.

Comment: Hi user2560730, may I know if my code has helped you in understanding trie deletions?

Comment: Sorry @yanhan, I found your code a little tricky to understand, so I tried figuring the trie deletions on my own, and fortunately I got it right. But thanks for your effort.